# What are MACROs in CSV or XLS files?

Tags: csv, xls

What are Macros in CSV or XLS files ? How to enable or disable them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros in this context are code embedded into an office file.  They can't be embedded into CSVs, which are plain text.  However, they are quite popular in Excel files.  See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd553655%28office.12%29.aspx) for a simple example of one.

In Office 2007, you can [disable macros](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/enable-or-disable-macros-in-office-documents-HA010031071.aspx#BM2) in the Trust Center.